# When can you rollback other people's posts?

Tags: support, editing

I have on a few occasions wanted to rollback other people's posts after suggested edits have been approved when they shouldn't have. For example; two hours ago I edited the title of a question just seconds after *coleopterist* had made all kinds of edits to it, and, because it was approved, all edits to the actual question was overwritten. If I could, I'd rollback to *coleopterist's* version.

When do you get to rollback other people's posts? Or, is that kind of action restricted to moderators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rollback is part of the '[edit questions and answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)' privilege - which you can gain with 1,000 reputation on this beta site.  You are only 21 points away from this already.

I think the logic is that if you can be trusted to make unreviewed edits, you can be trusted to roll back revisions.

Comment: *"You are only 21 points away from this already."* - Oh, much less to review then. ;)

Comment: @ChristianRau haha yeah, but who's gonna help you get those review badges now? ;)